# EncryptedXml OAEP - null reference issue

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, encryption

so I have one issue with EncryptedXml decrypting using OAEP. I have part of code which encrypts some xml like this:

```
        ...
        byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, true);

        EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
        edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
        edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSAOAEPUrl);
        ...
```

when I try to decrypt it like this:

```
        EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(document);
        var provider = (RSA)_certificate.PrivateKey;
        exml.AddKeyNameMapping("rsaKey", provider);
        exml.DecryptDocument();
```

EncryptedXml throws exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

And in stack trace is this method: at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, String symmetricAlgorithmUri)

When I'm using EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url everything is fine and it works without problem. But I need use EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSAOAEPUrl.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I only see a session key in the first code block and an RSA private key in the other. Either you've posted too little code, or there is some odd mismatch between keys

Comment: I've found what was the problem. I was encrypting data with assymetric key and key with symetric aes256. So I have switched encrypting methods and everything is fine. Now, it makes sense to me, to encrypt key with assymetric key (public) and data with symetric session key, and then decrypt key with private key and data with this decrypted key. It was just dumb mistake.

Comment: Glad you got it solved user1275513, if you want I can make my comment an answer or if you want you can make it one yourself. Stupid mistakes are ones you cannot find :)